# How to share the binaries of a rust project that uses gstreamer-rs

Tags: rust, gstreamer, packaging

I am learning rust by building a cli. The project uses gstreamer-rs. So far it works well on my machine but I still can't figure out how to distribute the binary.

**[The project](https://github.com/nsrcodes/spur) and the [test realease](https://github.com/nsrCodes/spur/releases/tag/test)**

Running `cargo build --release` builds a target that is around `500 MB` large.
I thought that I could ask my friend to install the required dependecies by `apt-install`ing the libraries that would appear in the error while he tried to run the binary from the release.
But from the error message, it seems like the binary stores the path to libraries on my machine (*`/home/nsrcodes/` is my home directory*)

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to make desktop-audio-encoder: BoolError { message: "Failed to create element from factory name", filename: "/home/nsrcodes/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gstreamer-0.17.4/src/auto/element_factory.rs", function: "gstreamer::auto::element_factory", line: 204 }', src/recorder.rs:79:14
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

what is the right way to distribute this?

Comment: The remembered path is just for the error message. All you need to redistribute is the file `target/release/spur`. The error is caused by some other problem.

Comment: In addition to that, you also need to make sure that the target environment has a new enough version of GStreamer, the plugins you use and any other C / system dependencies your application uses.

Comment: Have your friend run your program with `export GST_DEBUG=3; spur`. This should enable extra GStreamer traces that will allow them to know which element GStreamer was unable to create, and hence which plugin they need to install.